# Cannot load pdf from local file system (IONIC 4 - Android)

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, ionic-framework

I got a problem where I cannot load a pdf inside a view of my app.

In my demo app for this I got two views, one "home" and one "result". In the home view I got a button which opens an android document picker with function `pickDocument()`. After a document has been picked the file name and file path get passed to the "result" view.

In my result view I convert the given path of the document picker to a native path in `setPath()`, but this path gives me a 404 on my device. I can't seem to load the file I want to display there.

The file has the local path (before converting it using `setPath()`:

> content://com.android.providers.downloads.documents/document/22

I get the following error:

> Dummy-PDF.pdf:1 GET http://localhost/_app_file_/storage/emulated/0/Download/Dummy-PDF.pdf 404 (OK)

Is there anything I am missing? Or is there a better way to do, what I am trying to do? Could someone please help me to fix this issue.

I included the important code parts below. Thanks a lot.

Code of **home.page.ts**

```
...

export class HomePage {

  constructor(private chooser: Chooser, private router: Router) { }

  pickDocument() {
    this.chooser.getFile("application/pdf")
      .then(file => {
        this.addFile(file.name, file.uri);
      }, error => {
        console.error(error);
      });
  }

  addFile(fileName: string, fileUri: string) {
    let navigationExtras: NavigationExtras = {
      queryParams: {
        "fileName": fileName,
        "fileUri": fileUri
      }
    };
    this.router.navigate(["result"], navigationExtras);
  }
}
```

Code of **result.page.ts**

```
...

export class ResultPage implements OnInit {

  public fileName: string;
  public fileUri: string;
  public path: string;
  private win: any = window;

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private filePath: FilePath) {
    this.route.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
      this.fileName = params["fileName"];
      this.fileUri = params["fileUri"];
      this.setPath();
    });
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  setPath() {
    this.filePath.resolveNativePath(this.fileUri).then(path => {
      this.path = this.win.Ionic.WebView.convertFileSrc(path);
    });
  }
}
```

Code of **result.page.html**

```
<ion-content>
    <ion-list>
        <ion-item>
            <ion-img [src]="path"></ion-img>
        </ion-item>
        <ion-item>FileName: {{fileName}}</ion-item>
        <ion-item>FileUri:{{fileUri}}</ion-item>
        <ion-item>FilePath:{{path}}</ion-item>
    </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```